# Writable dex file is not allowed?

Tags: java, android

the full error is "Writable dex file '/data/data/com.example.tasklist/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex' is not allowed."

I did not make the code the error is for, its a school assignment where we just copy the powerpoint. Nothing in the code is underlined red and I've relooked at the powerpoint 3 times for spelling errors. The assignment for context is making a Task List DataBase. I'm not sure where to start looking and if you need the full error I'll update this post with it.

Comment: Use Android Studio Girafe.

Comment: That is the Android "Write xor Execute" security restriction on recent Android versions. Dex files are not allowed in the writable data path of an app.

Comment: @blackapps i have to use dolphin :(

Comment: @Robert i dont know what is or isnt a dex files. And by path do you mean the path of the file location?

Answer (score 6):

Use the current version of Android Studio, like Girafe of Hedgehog. Older versions change the dex files to r/w, so if you're targeting Android 14 the app will not deploy correctly.